# 'exert' : How can you 'attach or join out' something?

Tags: etymology, english

> ## [exert (v.)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/exert#etymonline_v_14050)
>
> 1660s, "thrust forth, push out," from Latin *exertus/exsertus*, past participle of *exerere/exserere* "thrust out, put forth," from ***ex*** "out, from within" (see [ex-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ex-?ref=etymonline_crossreference)) + ***serere*** "attach, join; arrange, line up" (from PIE root [*ser-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*ser-?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_52708) (2) "to line up").
>
> [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/66113?rskey=mN3GMj&result=2&isAdvanced=false): ... The formation is `probably` due to antithesis with inserĕre ([to insert v.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/96769)) ...

How did  ***ex-*** + ***serere*** compound to mean the modern meaning above of "thrust forth, push out"? How does it make sense to "attach/join out" something?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really.

"Insert" (or rather its ancestor *in-serere*) arose naturally, meaning "to bind into" and later "to insert".

Then, when people wanted an opposite for "insert" (something like "to pull out"), it made sense to swap *in-* for *ex-*, its opposite.